# Adding an image to bootstrap jumbotron with CodeIgniter Framework for PHP

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I need help with adding an image, as the background, to a Bootstraps jumbotron in the Codeigniter Framework for PHP.

I currently can add an image to Codeigniter no problem with the following code:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('image/test.jpg'); ?>">
```

I can also use my CSS file to change the background of the jumbotron with the following code:

```
.jumbotron {
color: black;
text-align: center;
background-color: red;}
```

however, I am not sure how to get the css file to add my image to the background of the jumbotron. I have tried the following:

```
.jumbotron {
color: black;
text-align: center;
background-image: <?php echo base_url('image/test.jpg'); ?> }

.jumbotron {
color: black;
text-align: center;
background-image: url('image/test.jpg');}

.jumbotron {
color: black;
text-align: center;
background-image: 'image/test.jpg'}
```

Nothing that I try seems to work. I do have my images folder under the project and not in the application folder. I can get the images to display anywhere on my page-that is not the problem. But getting them as the background in the jumbotron does not work.

Comment: On your css you could use `background-image: url('../image/test.png');` image is a folder in main directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing is to apply it in your view to the Jumbotron.

Try something like this in your view:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url('<?= base_url('image/test.jpg'); ?>')">
    ...
</div>
```

You can still do the rest of your styling for the background image e.g. `background-size` in CSS for your jumbotron.

CSS files won't be parsed by PHP unless you specifically change your server to parse them or output them from PHP files with a CSS extension.

The background image when manually specified in CSS in your example wouldn't have worked because you had a relative path to specify the image location. E.g. the browser would have looked for the picture at `/css/image/test.jpg` rather than `/image/test.jpg`. If you specif `background-image: url('/image/test.jpg')` in your CSS it should work.

Comment: Daniel thank you for the help! It worked and was actually quite easy. Thank you for the background information as well! Have a great day and start to your week!